# Overlapping fills

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a graphic representing a stack of rectangles.  I would ideally like a simple command like \stack{5} to create a stack of 5.

I can use the following code:

```
\draw[fill=blue] (0.4,-0.4) rectangle +(3,2);
\draw[fill=blue] (0.3,-0.3) rectangle +(3,2);
\draw[fill=blue] (0.2,-0.2) rectangle +(3,2);
\draw[fill=blue] (0.1,-0.1) rectangle +(3,2);
\draw[fill=blue] (0.0,-0.0) rectangle +(3,2);
```

[image]

However, it seems hard to turn that into a command, and if we need to shift the stack around it is a hassle to change all of the coordinates. I was thinking this might be better:

```
\draw[fill=blue] (0.4,-0.4)
  rectangle +(3,2) ++(-0.1,0.1)
  rectangle +(3,2) ++(-0.1,0.1)
  rectangle +(3,2) ++(-0.1,0.1)
  rectangle +(3,2) ++(-0.1,0.1)
  rectangle +(3,2) ++(-0.1,0.1);
```

[image]

This has the advantage that shifting it around only changes the coordinates in one obvious place, and it is even a little more clear about what is intended.

Unfortunately, this second version fills all the rectangles first, and then draws their outlines, so the "top" rectangle does not cover the rest of the stack.

Is there a simple way to draw overlapping regions using relative draw commands?

Comment: Scope the first one and shift that scope to move around.

Comment: No problem. I strongly recommend that you always include them. (Accidental rap rhyme :P)

Comment: [Creating stacked shapes for tikzstyle with](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40744/creating-stacked-shapes-for-tikzstyle-with) provides other solutions to draw stacked rectangles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution that exploits the fact that paths constructed using the `edge` command are separate and thus are drawn separately.  An `edge` path is as flexible as a `to` path so can be adapted to draw just about anything, including a rectangle.  So we define a new `to path` and an `edge` style that invokes. it.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68555/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  edge rectangle/.style={
    to path={ rectangle (\tikztotarget)}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[every edge/.append style={edge rectangle,fill=blue}] (0.4,-0.4)
  edge +(3,2) ++(-0.1,0.1)
  edge +(3,2) ++(-0.1,0.1)
  edge +(3,2) ++(-0.1,0.1)
  edge +(3,2) ++(-0.1,0.1)
  edge +(3,2) ++(-0.1,0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following:

[image: stacked rectangles via edge commands]

Comment: Thanks this is more what I was looking for! At first the idea of an edge drawing a rectangle seems a bit odd, but now seems pretty natural.  This lets me use relative drawing commands, so I can position labels and other decorations based on one initial coordinate.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply package everything up in to a command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\stack}[3][5]{  
\foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
 { \draw[fill=blue] (\x/10,-\x/10) rectangle +(#2,#3); }
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \stack{3}{2};
  \stack[2]{-2}{3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Is there a typo, #3 is never used?

Comment: At a guess, the coordinates should be `(#2,#3)`.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Andrew Stacey is right.  Code corrected now and picture updatede.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution based on Andrew Swann's answer:

[image: rendered version of the tex]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% \stack{5}{(4,0)}{(3,2)}{Label} draws a stack of 5 at (4,0) with dimensions (3,2)
% and labels the center with "Label"
\newcommand{\stack}[4]{
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {
    \draw[fill=blue!50] #2 ++({0.1*(#1)},{-0.1*(#1)}) ++({-0.1*\i},{0.1*\i}) rectangle +#3;
  }
  \path #2 -- +#3 node[pos=0.5] {#4};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\stack{5}{(0,0)}{(3,2)}{I}
\stack{3}{(4,0)}{(3,2)}{II}
\stack{1}{(8,0)}{(3,2)}{III}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```