# Make boxes extend backwards one on top of the other

Tags: tikz-pgf

I don't know how to word this, but I want that `1..n` effect where you can tell that there are boxes behind the top one and it is assumed that they are all the same. Perhaps this picture will help (I'm sorry but I couldn't find a better picture online, just pretend the DVDs are `tikz` boxes).

[image]

Just to clarify, what I what is that top right hand corner effect where you can tell there are, in this case, DVDs behind the current DVD

Can someone provide a minimal `tikz` code to achieve this affect?

Comment: For two or three copies you can use `copy shadow` and `double copy shadow` options otherwise you just put filled rectangles inside a `\foreach` loop.

Comment: The question should maybe be rephrased. I thought of TeX boxes containing `tikzpicture`s that should be stacked …

Comment: A similar question: [Overlapping fills](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68555/overlapping-fills).

Answer (score 11):

## Less than four copies

As mentioned in comment, for fewer than four copies you can use the `copy shadow` or `double copy shadow` options available in the `shadows` library.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [draw, ultra thick, fill=white,rounded corners, double copy shadow={ultra thick, shadow xshift=0.5cm, shadow yshift=0.5cm}] (0,0) rectangle +(-4,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## For at least four copies

You can use a `\foreach` loop. Improve this.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}% 
    \fill [draw, ultra thick, fill=white,rounded corners] (-\x/2,-\x/2) rectangle +(-4,6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Edit

I replaced `1,2,3,4` in the `\foreach` loop as suggested by Peter Grill.

Comment: I'd replace the `1,2,3,4` with `1,...,4` as then it is easier to modify.