# tikz customize file archive shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to use pgfdeclareshape draw a file archive shape.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{mrects}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]
    \foreach \i in {center,north,south,east,west} {
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\i}
    }
    \anchor{text} {
        \pgfpoint{-0.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}{-0.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox}
    }
    \backgroundpath{
        % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
        \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        % construct main path
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathclose
        % my code
        \newdimen\pgf@xd
        \newdimen\pgf@yd
        \newdimen\pgf@xe
        \newdimen\pgf@ye
        \newdimen\pgf@xg
        \newdimen\pgf@yg
        \newdimen\pgf@xh
        \newdimen\pgf@yh
        %
        \pgf@xg=\pgf@xa
        \pgf@yg=\pgf@yb
        \pgf@xh=\pgf@xb
        \pgf@yh=\pgf@ya
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i*2)] in {1,...,2} {
            \pgf@xd=\pgf@xg \advance\pgf@xd by \j pt
            \pgf@yd=\pgf@yg \advance\pgf@yd by \j pt
            \pgf@xe=\pgf@xh \advance\pgf@xe by \j pt
            \pgf@ye=\pgf@yh \advance\pgf@ye by \j pt
            % add line
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xd}{\pgf@yg}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xd}{\pgf@yd}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xe}{\pgf@yd}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xe}{\pgf@ye}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xh}{\pgf@ye}}
            \pgf@xg=\pgf@xd
            \pgf@yg=\pgf@yd
            \pgf@xh=\pgf@ye
            \pgf@yh=\pgf@ye 
        }   
    }
    \foregroundpath{
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,mrects,minimum width=6em,minimum height=2em] (N1) {hello world};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But two issues need your help:

1. The text not at the center.
2. The `north west` and `south east` corner lines crossed together.sounds line the assignment at the end of `foreach` loop doesn't work.

Comment: I would be very careful with using a `\foreach` loop in a shape declaration. If you use the thing in another foreach loop over `\i` you will get even more surprised than you already are.

Comment: do you look *69.3.2 Copy Shadows* in tikz & pgf manual, pp 757 (v 3.1)?  there is described `double copy shadow`, which seem to do what you like to achieve ...

Comment: duplicate?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316455/multiple-object-instances-represented-by-two-slightly-shifted-rectangles/316544#316544

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Zarko pointed, a `double copy shadow` solves your problem:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[double copy shadow,
        fill=white,
        draw=black,
        minimum width=6em,
        minimum height=2em] (N1) {Hello World};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]