# 3D image stack with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw a 3D image stack with tikz? (See the image below)

[image]

Comment: I think we've already seen this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316455/1952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the recommendations of Ignasi and Claudio Fiandrino, the best solution is probably to use the shadows library.
See the example below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{imageStack/.style={
            draw=black, 
            double copy shadow={shadow xshift=5ex, shadow yshift=2.5ex}, 
            fill=white, 
            inner sep=0}}
    \node [imageStack] (exampleImageStack) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Source: https://mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example that defines a new `\imagestack` command. The stack is created by drawing the frames in the background on a background layer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{bg}    
    % set the order of the layers (main is the standard layer)  
    \pgfsetlayers{bg,main}  
    % \imagestack{image_name}{position}{path_to_image}
    \newcommand{\imagestack}[3] {   
        \node[inner sep=0, draw] (#1) at (#2) {\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{#3}};
        \coordinate (offset) at (0.05cm, 0.05cm);
        % draw on the background layer
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}    
            \foreach \i in {3,...,1}
            \filldraw[draw=black, fill=white] ($(#1.south east) + \i*(offset)$) rectangle ($(#1.north west) + \i*(offset)$);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    }
    \imagestack{image}{{0,0}}{example-image-a}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's no really need for complex definitions: check what copy `shadow` does (from the `shadows` library).

Comment: Thank you for the advice :)