# Create node of same size as fitted node, but displaced slightly

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I want to repeat a node multiple times, but displaced each time, something like:

[image]

However, in my case, the top node is a fitted node, that contains some other nodes. I do not know the size of the fitted node. So I dont know how big to make the nodes underneath. The nodes underneath should be blank, nothing drawn in them (unlike my example above). How can I create nodes that are the exact same size as the top fitted node?

By the way, the code to produce the pictured example was:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro\exx{\i * 0.2};
  \pgfmathsetmacro\exy{\i * 0.2};
  \node [block, xshift=\exx cm, yshift=\exy cm] (inner_example) {This is some text};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

(but in my actual case, I don't want to just repeat the drawing in each of the lower nodes, since it is a complicated picture, and seems wasteful to do so.)

Comment: You may create a `pic` where you draw everything (your nodes and your fitting node), then use it into your `foreach` loop. Would you mind sharing the complete MWE, if you don't know how to proceed?

Comment: Apart from that, your question remains unclear to me. Maybe should you share a sketch of what you need.

Comment: Like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316544/1952

Comment: @Ignasi   Yes :)  That's what I was looking for, right :)