# Possibility to build this in TEX?

Tags: graphs, charts, organisation

im writing my thesis and have a question. Is it possible to build this in tex what i posted in the picture?[image: Flowshop]

Im new in to tex... Dont be so harsh with me.

Greets!

Comment: Welcome! :) It's not about harshness. The answer to your question is yes, absolutely you can, TikZ (or PS tricks if you prefer) are capable of this, it can be done in TeX. However, it's not really reasonable to expect the community to do it for you. If you're lucky somebody may, but you shouldn't expect it. So if you're actual question is the one you ask - can it be done? the answer is yes, you can [learn TikZ](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) and do this in LaTeX if you want

Comment: hey, its not my intention that someone build it for me i just need some help, i know the tikz package but i found nothing that could look like my picture =)

Comment: However, it's a steep learning curve and a lot of work. Most of the time, unless you want to start doing diagrams in TeX generally, or you know TikZ, it wouldn't be worth it for one picture, and you should insert it as an image. Or maybe you'll get lucky and someone will draw it for you.

Comment: i wont to build something similiar my own. But i did not find anything in tikz that suits what i want =)

Comment: Well as I say, that's the manual, you won't find a template for every possible picture, you'll have to start from the ground up and ask here if you have very specific questions. For example, I'm sure you can make a start on the little flowchart at the bottom and come here if you get stuck. Again, I'm sure you can find out how to draw rectangles in the manual. Either you must be prepared to learn TikZ the hard way, or you can insert it as an image (which I would do in your position), or you know maybe someone will make a start for you. But that isn't what you asked.

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is: Yes.

Comment: For such tasks, my usual approach is to do an image search to find something which already has a similar structure and then modify from there https://www.google.de/search?q=latex+tikz+flow+shop&client=firefox-b-ab&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvpu7Yg-jQAhXLbRQKHU8QBBcQ_AUICCgB

Comment: Some inspiration: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254074 Most of that is just filled rectangles and text, so (small variations of) `\node [draw=black,fill=<color>,minimum width=<length>,minimum height=<length>] at (x,y) {<text>};` does almost everything you need fornthe diagram. There might well be several ways of shortening the code though.

Comment: Please consider accepting answers to your questions if they have resolved the issue you wanted help with.

Comment: Click the green tickmark (Häkchen) left of the answer that helped you most, also consider giving it an upvote/like. You can like multiple answers.

Comment: Ping doesn't work if you leave a space. However, @Johannes_B answered anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you want be quickly to realize your picture without to know very well `TikZ` and `PSTricks`, you can use:

- `LaTeXDraw` is a graphical drawing editor for LaTeX. LaTeXDraw can be used to 1) generate PSTricks code; 2) directly create PDF or PS pictures;
- `IPE`;
- `XFig` or `WinFig`;
- `InkScape` see the link https://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/.